# Copy an existing graphics:

Tags: r, video, graphics

I'm a French student in Biology and I am having difficulties with Rstudio. Indeed, I'm supposed to remake an existing graphic with just an image of it and the dataset that was used to do it. It needs to be EXACTLY as in the image (except for the color). Can you help me ?

This is the image that I need to reproduce (using only "ggplot2" and "dplyr"):

[image: Plot I am trying to recreate]

and this is the one I came up with :

[image: Plot I have created]

this is the code that I used :

```r
setwd("C:/MASTER/S8/OBG/MDR/MDR3")

tab_movies = read.table(file = "movies2.csv", header=T, sep = ",",quote = "\"")

tab_ratings = read.table(file = "ratings.csv", h = T, sep = ",", quote = "\"")

tab_tags = read.table(file = "tags.csv",h = T, sep = ",", quote = "\"")

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

tab_movies = 
  tab_movies %>%
  mutate(decade = (year - (year %% 10))) %>% 
  filter(year>= 1930 & year<= 2010)

movie_ratings_joined =
  tab_movies %>%
  left_join(tab_ratings, by = "movieId")

filmrating =
  movie_ratings_joined %>%
  group_by(movieId) %>%
  mutate(average_rating = mean(rating)) %>%
  mutate(nb.ratings = length(rating))

#fonctionne partiellement (affiche un graphique)

ggex6 =
  ggplot(filmrating, aes(decade), na.rm = T, alpha (0.3)) +

  geom_point(aes(x = decade, y = average_rating,
                 col = as.factor(decade), size = nb.ratings)) +

  labs(title = "Average rating per decade",
       subtitle = "(films with more than 50 ratings)",
       caption = "Source : https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/",
       y = "average rating")

plot(ggex6)
```

You can find the dataset with this link :

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18jxW7RnNYua_zjou2LnPUWASZBsrU8Wo?usp=drive_link

I have been working on it for several hours now, hope someone can help, I am currently going crazy.

Thanks for your attention,

Bulle5156

Comment: Try with `geom_jitter` instead of `geom_point`. Additionally `alpha` is a parameter of the geom, i.e. use something like `geom_jitter(aes(...), ..., alpha = .3)`.

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow! Seems like you're almost there. However I notice, in the original graphic there are only films with more than 50 ratings. In your graphic, there are all films. A little bit of `dplyr` can preselect your dataset to only this subset of films with at least 50 ratings. Then add the `alpha = 0.4` argument and you achieve the same look as in the original graphic

Comment: @stefan thank you for your help, unfortunately even if I managed to filter the movies by the nb of ratings, and change geom_point by geom_jitter, I'm still stuck with this graph, and the point won't become transparent with the "alpha=0.3" fonction, Now with the geom_jitter I have like ovals on the side, nothing like the image I'm suppose to get

Comment: @uke thank you for your help, but the alpha did nothing to my graph, where am I suppose to put it ?

Comment: Sorry  I did not specify that. You are supposed to put it where @stefan explained. supply it inside the parentheses of your `geom_...` function as an argument. as suggested by @stefan, the original graphic uses `geom_jitter()`, so probably you want to replace `geom_point()` with `geom_jitter()`.

Comment: `alpha` is not a function, but it is just a plain argument in this case. Do not use it like `alpha(.4)`, use it like this: `alpha = .4`. Consider removing your use of `alpha(.4)` inside the parentheses of `ggplot()`.

Comment: @uke well I tried to change geom_point by geom_jitter and I moved the alpha = 0.4 inside the parentheses of ggplot(), it still doesn't work : with jitter my points become long ovals , and the alpha=.4 changed nothing ^^'.

Comment: @uke This is my code now and I still don't get why it is not working : ggex6 = ggplot(filmrating, aes(decade), na.rm = T) + 
  geom_jitter(aes(x = decade,
                 y = average_rating,
                 col=as.factor(decade),
                 alpha=0.4,
                 size = nb.ratings)) +
  labs(title = "Average rating per decade",
       subtitle = "(films with more than 50 ratings)",
       caption = "Source : https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/",
       y = "average rating")
plot(ggex6)

Comment: @uke I changed "decade" by "year" in the geom_point() and it's better, but it's still not transparent, but that's okay enough , thank you very much for your help !

Comment: You should set alpha outside the parentheses of `aes()` but inside the parentheses of `geom_jitter()`. The reason: If you put it inside `aes()`, ggplot will think you want to map a variable to some aesthetic attribute `alpha`. Everything you place outside `aes()` will not be variable, but fixed on a single value. That is what you want for `alpha` in this case.